# Usar CONTINUE en un SWITCH

Tags: java

Lo que quiero es que el programa vuelva atrás para volver a ejecutar un switch si es que llega a entrar en el opción por defecto, se que podría hacerse utilizando un bucle pero la cosa es evitar usarlos. Aquí dejo mi ejemplo:

```
error:
    switch(empezar){
        case "start": System.out.println("En breves comenzaras, recuerda que tu puntuacion inicial es 0 y deberas llegar como minimo a 5 para pasar este test.");
            break;
        case "cancelar":System.out.println("Vuelve cuando estes preparado."); System.exit(0);
            break;
        case "salir": System.out.println("Gracias por jugar.");System.exit(0);
            break;
        default: System.out.println("No es un comando valido.");
            continue error;
    }
```

Comment: Deberias meter todo dentro de un do{ switch.... }while (!error);....

Comment: La cosa es que no quiero utilizar ningún bucle,como he mencionado en la descripción de la pregunta. ¿Sería posible? @Tegito123

Comment: Porqué no querrías usar un bucle, es la forma normal en que se haría esto.

Comment: No es que no quiera, es que aun no podemos hacerlo, entonces buscaba una solución sin utilizar bucles ni funciones ni nada, con las instrucciones mas básicas posibles.

Comment: Primeramente `continue` no se puede usar fuera de un bucle. Segundo, no le veo ningún sentido a lo que dices: volver a ejecutar el `switch` en caso de que entre en el `default` así sin más. Tu `switch` es para evaluar el valor de `empezar`, se supone que antes de volver al principio el valor de `empezar` debería cambiar en caso de que haya entrado en el `default` **¿dónde o cómo cambiarías el valor de `empezar`** ya que si vuelves al principio sin cambiar su valor, estarías creando una especie de **bucle infinito**? Una posible solución sería una bandera booleana y un `if`...

Comment: Tienes razon en lo de cambiar el valor de empezar, en ese caso el codigo quedaria tal que asi:  `error: empezar = sc.nextLine(); switch(empezar){... default: continue error;}` de manera que lo que busco es que si se introduce una cadena que no esta valorada en el `switch` el usuario vuelva a introducir una nueva cadena.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es posible utilizar `break;` o `continue;` fuera de un bucle.